# Checking CPython configuration options

Tags: configure, cpython

I switched to Python 3.11.4 and got some problem when importing some modules. So, I decided to try different configuration options in order to find the right combination(s). The problem seems to be fixed but now if I want to check the configurations with `sysconfig` I cannot see them.

Here the new setup

```
Python-3.11.4 $ ./configure --with-pydebug \
                            --enable-loadable-sqlite-extensions \
                            --enable-shared \
                            --with-computed-gotos \
                            --enable-optimizations \
                            --with-system-ffi \
Python-3.11.4 $ make -s -j2
Python-3.11.4 $ sudo make altinstall
Python-3.11.4 $ ./python
>>> import sysconfig
>>> print(sysconfig.get_config_vars('CONFIG_ARGS')[0])

# nothing, empty list
```

With the old python's version it works perfectly.